# How to create duplicate tables with 'similar' names of a column of a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains the names of tables.
The structure is the following:

```
table_name  
dbo.2017_10_8   
dbo.2017_10_19
dbo.2017_10_30
dbo.2017_11_10
dbo.2017_11_21
dbo.2017_12_2
dbo.2017_12_13
dbo.2017_12_24
dbo.2018_1_4
dbo.2018_1_15
dbo.2018_1_26
dbo.2018_2_6
dbo.2018_2_17
dbo.2018_3_11
dbo.2018_2_28
```

I would like to create tables that have name of table like

```
dbo.2017_10_8_cs
dbo.2017_10_19_cs
dbo.2017_10_30_cs
dbo.2017_11_10_cs
dbo.2017_11_21_cs
dbo.2017_12_2_cs
dbo.2017_12_13_cs
dbo.2017_12_24_cs
dbo.2018_1_4_cs
dbo.2018_1_15_cs
dbo.2018_1_26_cs
dbo.2018_2_6_cs
dbo.2018_2_17_cs
dbo.2018_3_11_cs
dbo.2018_2_28_cs
```

I know that if for example *t* contains the first block of values.
I can just

```
select table_name + '_cs' from t
```

and then I have the names in the format I want, but how can I create all tables with the name of the table having the second block of values? Thank you in advance

Comment: CREATE TABLE maybe...

Comment: If you want to `CREATE` a table, you need to give it columns as well. What columns should it have? A statement `CREATE TABLE dbo.2018_2_17_cs;` is going to fail. This, however, smells of poor database design; what is your true goal here?

Comment: CREATE TABLE dbo.2018_2_17_cs(
[m_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
                    [message] [varchar] (150),
                    [orig] [nvarchar] (256),
                    [recip] [nvarchar] (256),
                    [size] [int] NULL)
would be something like this. 
But my question is how to dynamically change every time this table_name in order to have second block names in each case (if possible).

Comment: I would like to:
1) create table dbo.[2018_2_17_cs]
2) copy data from dbo.[2018_2_17] to dbo.[2018_2_17_cs]
3) drop table dbo.[2018_2_17]

Comment: Your statement doesn't make any sense. At a guess you want to create 15 identical tables, apart from they have different names. Again, why? Why not have a single table with a column denoting your category (for example `'2018_2_6_cs'`); this is proper normalisation.

Comment: Why `CREATE` and DROP`? Why not rename the objects?

Comment: well I am making some experiments about certain indexes performance and I want the second table to have the same data as the first but adding new indexes. Is it possible to progress with this idea? Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166831/discussion-between-alexithymia-and-larnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CURSOR` to cycle each table.

```
DECLARE @SourceTableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DestinationTableName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE TableNameCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        SouceTableName = QUOTENAME(table_name),
        DestinationTableName = QUOTENAME(table_name + '_cs')
    FROM
        t

OPEN TableNameCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableNameCursor INTO @SourceTableName, @DestinationTableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DynamicSQLCreate VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @DestinationTableName + ' FROM ' + @SourceTableName

    DECLARE @DynamicSQLDrop VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP TABLE ' + @SourceTableName

    EXEC (@DynamicSQLCreate)

    EXEC (@DynamicSQLDrop)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableNameCursor INTO @SourceTableName, @DestinationTableName

END

CLOSE TableNameCursor
DEALLOCATE TableNameCursor
```

Please note that I used `SELECT INTO` to create your new tables. This command will copy the source table structure and load it with all it's data, **but not it's indexes or constraints**.

You can switch the `EXEC` for a `PRINT` to validate the script before actually executing.

**EDIT:**

You can use the system stored procedure `sp_rename` to change the new table to the original one (once dropped). Put this inside the while loop:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLCreate VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @DestinationTableName + ' FROM ' + @SourceTableName
DECLARE @DynamicSQLDrop VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP TABLE ' + @SourceTableName
DECLARE @DynamicSQLRename VARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC sp_rename ' + @DestinationTableName + ' , ' + @SourceTableName

EXEC (@DynamicSQLCreate)
EXEC (@DynamicSQLDrop)
EXEC (@DynamicSQLRename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)

Comment: Please mark as answered if it solved your problem. Glad to help :)